# WCF - Send callback without a Clientcall

Tags: c#, wcf

I use a DuplexChannelFactory to send callbacks to my clients.
I would like to send those callbacks before a client call was made.

In other words the moment a Channel is opened via DuplexChannelFactory.CreateChannel() I wish to send a Callback to the client that just opened this channel.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because you don't have callback channel available in the service. Client must be the one who initiate communication. Moreover I'm almost sure (I didn't checked it) that `CreateChannel` doesn't open the connection but the first client call does.